# Accessing children of a fragment from Fragment activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a fragment defined as

```
public class AddValue extends Fragment 
{
    private int position;
    public EditText addEdit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Log.e("Test", "hello");
       position = getArguments().getInt("position");

    }

 /**
  * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
  */     
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_value, container, false);


       addEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editBox);

       if (position == 0)
           addEdit.setHint("Patient Id");
       if (position == 1)
           addEdit.setHint("Age");
       if (position == 2)
           addEdit.setHint("Height In Inches");
       if (position == 3)
           addEdit.setHint("Weight in lbs");
       if (position == 4)
           addEdit.setHint("LA Volume Index");



       return view;
     }

}
```

I have one `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`

now i am using this

```
FragAdapter myAdapter = (FragAdapter)   mPager.getAdapter();
             AddValue screen  = (AddValue) myAdapter.getItem(myPosition);
             EditText box = (EditText) screen.getView().findViewById(R.id.editBox);


    public class FragAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {
        public FragAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) 
        {
            AddValue val = new AddValue();
            Fragment frag = val;
            Bundle arg = new Bundle();
            arg.putInt("position", position);  
            frag.setArguments(arg);
            return frag;
        }

    }
```

How can i access EditText from my mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks quite some structure. Where exactly do you want to reach the EditText? Why do you want this? Maybe a different set up would be better.

Anyway, you could make the EditText a public static variable so easily reach it from anywhere. This is in most cases not a nice way to handle things though.

Comment: i want to set Text in editText at some place, however i get null pointer at ragAdapter myAdapter = (FragAdapter)   mPager.getAdapter();
             AddValue screen  = (AddValue) myAdapter.getItem(myPosition);
             EditText box = (EditText) screen.getView().findViewById(R.id.editBox);

Comment: I am doing voice recognition, and its onActivityResult I am settings whatever its recorded as text in EditText

Answer (score 0):

If your `AddValue` fragment is instantiated from xml, then you can this way: 
In onActivityResult add these: 
`AddValue fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.host_fragment)`

`host_fragment` is the id of the fragment from xml.

`if(fragment != null){` 
`fragment.setText(textFromSpeech);` 
`}`

And in `AddValue` fragment add method `public void setText(String text) { this.addEdit = text;}`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

```
 EditText text = (EditText) mPager.getChildAt(myPosition).findViewById(R.id.editBox);
         text.setText(matches.get(0));
```

Comment: Should've be more explicit from the start. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can access with getView method of Fragment class.

For example You have a TextView in Your MyFragment with id of "text_view"  
In Your Activity make a Fragment of Yours:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
```

And when You need a child just call getView and then find Your childView.

```
View view = myFragment.getView();
if (view !=null) {
view.findViewById(R.id.text_view).setText("Child Accessed :D");
}
```